# Get index of String between unique chars, then remove those chars and apply font to string in C#

Tags: c#, string, format, substring, npoi

so I hope someone here may help me.

My Situation:

I'm using NPOI in C# to export some things to excel. For that, I am also using `HSSFRichTextString`to have multiple fonts in one cell.

So, the "cell in need" should look like this: [image]

My Problem here lies in the formating of the "little Numbers" after each article, e.g. `3,20`.

To have an entrypoint for using string-comparison, I tried to add ### before the values which worked fine, but I can't figure out how to apply the correct font to the correct substrings (all of them in `menuCellContent`.

Here's my code so far (I tried a lot of things with stringfunctions, but nothing worked so I think I'll go for the startingpoint so far..), I think it'll make things a little bit clearer (sorry, german here):

```
var richString = new HSSFRichTextString(menuCellcontent + "\n" + nutrientCellContent);
richString.ApplyFont(0, menuCellcontent.split('###')[0], menuFont);
richString.ApplyFont(menuCellcontent.split('###')[0] + 1, (menuCellcontent + "\n" + nutrientCellContent).Length, nutrientFont);
menuCell.SetCellValue(richString);
```

but this results in the following output:

[image: wrong]

which is also not what I want to achieve. I tried for the last few hours to find a string method to generate the desired output, but somehow I always failed. Would be grat if someone here can help me! I think I just have a real knot in my brain..

Best regards,
goide